# Customize body error message - Spring boot REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to customize my body error message.

My springboot version is 2.1.5.RELEASE

I want this:

```
{
"This should be application specific"
}
```

but I'm receiving this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-05-24T15:47:10.872+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Not Found (404)",
    "path": "/github/gifojhuinh4w5"
}
```

My exception class is:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse,
                new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }
}
```

My class where exception is captured

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class GitHub {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/github/{usuario}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> quantidadeRepositorios(@PathVariable(value = "usuario")String usuario) throws IOException {

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService();
        GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        client.setOAuth2Token("key");

        map.put("Total",service.getRepositories(usuario).size()); // exception captured here

        return new ResponseEntity<>(gson.toJson(map), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: why the ```@EnableAutoConfiguration``` on your controller? are you sure the request is entering ```quantidadeRepositorios```?

Comment: if I remove @EnableAutoConfiguration, this error is shown:

Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException

Comment: if you use ```@SpringBootApplication``` you should not have to add an extra ```@EnableAutoConfiguration```. I guess there is something wrong with your application setup [springbootapplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exception is caught by ExceptionHandler, build a response entity and return it as below.

Create a ErrorResponseDTO object and set message to it.

```
public class ErrorResponseDTO {

    private String errorMessage;

}
```

In exception handler, return that dto object.

```
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponseDTO errorDTO = new ErrorResponseDTO();
        errorDTO.setErrorMessage("This should be application specific");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDTO, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

This will give you the payload, you are looking for.

```
{
"This should be application specific"
}
```